# API Gateway using Ocelot on .NET 6 docker container - unable to make it work

Tags: docker, microservices, .net-6.0, ocelot

I'm fairly new to the microservices architecture and hand cranked my own api-gateway which works, but from research realised the value in using Ocelot as a replacment due to the features it brings.  Today I created a new empty .NET 6 api-gateway project and using the Ocelot documentation brought in nuget packages needed to set it up.  The end game is to use Eureka, but as I don't seem to be able to make it work I have stepped back to using a direct call the docker based microservice first.

Looking at the documentation I think I've follow it to the letter, but when I launch the container it does nothing, I wonder if someone could point me in the right direction.

My program.cs

```
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        config
            .SetBasePath(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
            .AddJsonFile("ocelot.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.AddOcelot();
        //.AddEureka();
    });

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
app.UseOcelot().Wait();

app.Run();
```

my ocelot.json

```
{
  "Routes": [
    // drugService API
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/TerminologyServices/SearchDrugs/{filter}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "drugservice",
          "Port": "80"
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/TerminologyServices/SearchDrugs/{filter}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
      "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5003"
  }
}
'''
```

Comment: My guess is that it's `localhost` in your BaseUrl that's causing the issue. In a container context, localhost is the container itself, so my guess is that Ocelot sees your requests, but then sees that they're not from localhost and then ignores them. I don't know Ocelot, so I can't offer a solution. Maybe try removing the BaseUrl config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing localhost for the container name used by the docker compose yaml in this case web.api.gateway solves this problem.